# Overflow error with function

Tags: vb.net, function, overflow, runtime-error

```
Public Function checkForChars(ByVal arrayOfChars As String(), ByVal stringToCheck As String) As Boolean
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim numEntries As Integer = arrayOfChars.Length - 1
        For i = 0 To numEntries
            If (stringToCheck.Contains(arrayOfChars(numEntries)) = True) Then
                Return True
            End If
        Next

        Return False

End Function
```

Hey, I'm using the above function to check a string for an array of characters, but if the string is too long it gives an arithmetic overflow error (suggesting that I've divided by 0). At the moment I'm actually using an integer value.toString, can someone shed some light on this?

Thanks

Comment: The length of the array is greater than the max. Integer value? This sounds too big and indicates that you should face the problem in a different way. Can you please explain where is a so big array coming from?

Comment: Can you tell us the exact error message and in which line you get the exception? Your code above is a bit weird. You check always the last string, then why do you loop over the entries?

Comment: Oops sorry, I modified a variable name and forgot to modify the rest of the code. Vlad's answer seems to have worked, thanks for you time guys... Always get the weirdest errors I do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some issues, I've modified it a little. Check if it works for you

```
Public Function checkForChars(arrayOfChars As String(), stringToCheck As String) As Boolean
    For i As Integer = 0 To arrayOfChars.Length - 1
        If stringToCheck.Contains(arrayOfChars(i)) Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next

    Return False
End Function
```